# How to tranfer column contents from one Excel document to another using applescript

Tags: excel, macos, automation, applescript

i have two excel document one is template and i want to copy the content from one excel document to the temple excel document using applescript.

Document 1
A B C
D E F

Document 2

I have to transfer contents from Document 1 to Document 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set myData to value of range "A1:C3" of worksheet "Sheet1" of workbook "Workbook1"
    set value of range "A1:C3" of worksheet "Sheet1" of workbook "Workbook2" to myData
end tell
```

EDIT

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set targetRange to "A1:C3"
    set sourceRange to range targetRange of worksheet "Sheet1" of workbook "Workbook1"
    set destRange to range targetRange of worksheet "Sheet1" of workbook "Workbook2"
    copy range sourceRange destination destRange
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..
I'm getting a error message "The variable myData is not defined."

Comment: Did you updated the values of "Sheet1", "Workbook1", and "Workbook2" to reflect the names of the sheets and workbooks you are actually using?